# Hide every first 3 elements in a series of div

Tags: jquery

I want to hide every first 3 elements in a series of div, when I press  keyboard button. I have tried using the jquery eq(1,2,3) for this but it is not working.  I am using the code:

```js
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 49) {
          $(".thing span:eq(1,2,3)").hide();
        }
  });
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;

  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: how about giving first 3 span another class and hide them??

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, but I can not give me some class or ID (bcoz I am not allowed and) as these will always come in random series and I always want to hide elements by their position like 1,2,3 or 3,4,5 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.eq()` syntax is incorrect but that's OK because you can use `.lt()` instead:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 49) {
    $(".thing").find("span:lt(4)").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;

  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice()` for this purpose. I edited my selector to remove further elements, when the button "1" is pressed more than once.

If you want to remove the first 3 visible elements per "thing" then press "2", multiple times if you want ...

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 49){ $(".thing span:not(:hidden)").slice(0,3).hide();}
  if (e.which == 50){ $(".thing").find("span:not(:hidden):lt(3)").hide();}
});
```

```css
.thing {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;

  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>

<div class="thing">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: Only appears to work on the first div, but maybe that's what the OP wants?